# Pass the address of a Python structure to a C function

Tags: python, c

I want to pass the address of a structure to a C program. In C I would use something like fun(&vendorRecord). I have tried various forms I have found on the internet but nothing works. Can someone give me a suggestion?

My structure looks like this:

```
class vendrRecord(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1                                            # pack the struct
    _fields_ = [
        ("vendorListNumber"      ,c_ubyte *(5)),
        ("vendorNumber"          ,c_ubyte *(5)),
        ]
```

My C structure looks like this:

```
struct  {
    unsigned char vendorListNumber[5];
    unsigned char vendorNumber[5];
} vendrRecord;
```

My C prototype looks like this:

```
void fun(void *record);
```

My C call looks like this:

```
fun(&vendrRecord);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
VendrRecord = vendrRecord()
fun(byref(VendrRecord))
```